# TinyMCE code indentation issue

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, tinymce, syntax-highlighting

I have integrated TinyMCE with rails 4.2.6 through cdn. Also I am using it's "codesample" plugin. Everything is working fine except when I add code and update the post. The code indentation messess up on the show page. I have used prismJS and prism.css files also. I am attaching the screenshot of show page that how the indentation is messing up.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to solve this issue but for now I discovered a workaround. TinyMCE produces the below code when I write a code inside it. This causes the indentation to break on my show page(I have no clue why)

```
<pre class="language-ruby"><code>def hello
  "Hello"
end</code></pre>
```

So to avoid the indentation issue I modified the above code with the below one.

```
<pre class="language-ruby"><code>
def hello
  "Hello"
end
</code></pre>
```

Attached screenshot below:
[image]